# How can I match by substring and bring me values from the substring dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, label

I have a problem trying to match & merge some information.
I have a table like this:

TABLE TAGS

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| biden says X | 4 |
| trump says Y | 5 |
| putin do something | 5 |
| The new iphone is great | 5 |
| whatever | 5 |

and then I want to match it with this table with the following values:

TABLE CATEGORIES

| key | categorie |
| --- | --- |
| putin | war |
| trump | politics |
| biden | politics |
| phone | technology |

So, what I have been able to do is to know which of these values are in my table by doing this:

`df_tags[df_tags.key.str.contains("|".join(categories.key))]`

And this is good because it brings me which values are matching string with substring

TABLE RESULT
TABLE TAGS

| STRING | BOOLEAN |
| --- | --- |
| biden says X | TRUE |
| trump says Y | TRUE |
| putin do something | TRUE |
| The new iphone is great | TRUE |
| whatever | FALSE |

But what I really would like to do would be to bring the values where these are matching. Something like this:

| TAGS.KEY | VALUE | CATEGORIES.KEY | CATEGORIE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| biden says X | TRUE | biden | politics |
| trump says Y | TRUE | biden | politics |
| putin do something | TRUE | putin | war |
| The new iphone is great | TRUE | phone | technology |
| whatever | FALSE | false | nan |

Anyone has any idea?

Thank you for your support guys.

Comment: Hi! It would help a lot to get a better (and faster answer) if you could paste some short lines of code showing how you do this. Just to understand libraries and methods you are using.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hello Javier, this is the point that I don't have any code, the only code I have is the small line of code to have the third table (TABLE RESULT TABLE TAGS) I put in my question. The rest of the code is just pandas reading the first two tables I present. So the question is if you have any clue about how could I obtain the 4th table I put.